# How to load pre trained FastText Word Embeddings using Gensim?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gensim, fasttext

I downloaded word embedding [from this link](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html). I want to load it in `Gensim` to do some work but I am not able to load it. I have found many resources and none of it is working. I am using `Gensim` version `4.1`.

I have tried

```
gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model('/home/admin1/embeddings/crawl-300d-2M.vec')
gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors('/home/admin1/embeddings/crawl-300d-2M.vec')
```

and it is showing me

```
NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
```

I went to try to load it using using `FastText.load('/home/admin1/embeddings/crawl-300d-2M.vec',)` but then it showed `UnpicklingError: could not find MARK`.

Also, using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the `NotImplementedError`, those are the one kind of full Facebook FastText model, `-supervised` mode, that Gensim does not support.

So sadly, the answer to "How do you load these?" is "you don't".

The `.vec` files contain just the full-word vectors in a plain-text format – no subword info for synthesizing OOV vectors, or supervised-classification output features. Those can be loaded into a `KeyedVectors` model:

```py
kv_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('crawl-300d-2M.vec')
```

Comment: I had already used that but it can't be trained further. Idea is to shift the weights of pre-trained towards my  custom data set of 2M lines. Anyways, I got the idea that it's not possible.

Comment: Aha. That's possible, but such fine-tuning is tricky, error-prone, & not well-supported in Gensim. I think expanding your own corpus is almost always better. (More related thoughts in another recent answer, as what you're trying to do comes up a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533179/gensim-train-not-updating-weights/70537767#70537767)

Comment: Any rough idea about important parameters? If I train my embedding from scratch, how would I know which one is better? There is no loss or something like that to compare per epoch? Loss given is in the end I think and I use it with `optuna` or `gridsearch`, it'll take a lot of time.

Comment: There's an internal loss (for word-to-word predictions) tha training is minimizing, but its reporting in Gensim is buggy, & it may not correlate w/ your downstream goals. Ultimately to choose between 2 diff models (off shelf, or from your own alternate paramter/data training runs), you need to create your own project-specific quantitative evaluations, that can check how well a model works for your needs. For example, if you can find, or incrementally grow, sets of docs that "should" be closer to each other than others, you can score models vs each other by how well they match that expectation.

Comment: This is exactly I was afraid of. Train an Embedding on some params -> Pass it to Model and then train it -> Repeat. It'll take a whole lot of time. Anyways, thanks for all the insights.